# Can anyone show me an example of Zoom Creep on Nikkor lenses?

Tags: lens, nikon, zoom, zoom-creep

Looking for some pictures which certainly demonstrating this problem on Nikkor lenses. I am about to purchase the lens and want to be able to distinguish.

Comment: http://www.textually.org/picturephoning/Holy%20Moly%20plans%20to%20self-censor%20paparazzi%20pictures%20of%20celebrities.jpeg   Zoom creeps ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I own an 18-200 VR and it has a bit of creep. If I have the camera hanging on a strap with the lens pointing down, it will sometimes slowly extend out to 200mm.  If I have it at 18mm, it will usually stay put, but if it's at 50mm or so, it may exhibit the creep.  It's not a big deal to me.

Here's a video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I5FmLiXiEx0

The zoom creep occurs (on the Nikon 18-200mm) when the lens is pointing more or less straight up or down.  In normal shooting mode, where the camera is horizontal, it won't be an issue.

There is a lock on the lens at 18mm.  So you can lock it for walking around.

Mine only creeps when I have the lens cap and (relatively heavy) polarising filter on.  With those removed, it will only creep if I really shake the camera.

Comment: Looks terrible to me... really hope my D7000 has zoom lock to overcome this.

Comment: I have the same lens and this is not a problem for me. It only happens when the camera is worn, not when I am shooting. When I pick it up for a shot, I am likely to change the zoom anyway, according to the desired composition.

Comment: Any zoom lock would be on the lens, not the camera body.

Comment: My 18-200 VRII also creeps when worn. Mine will not creep from 18mm, but will creep from any other setting. I have a NC filter on the lens, and rarely have the lens cap on. The zoom lock sounds like a neat feature, but it's kinda a pain in practice. My girlfriend combats creep on her 18-200 by employing a rubber band bracelet on the lens barrel. Look at the green band on the lens https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/RIjnQWyKOil1vMkINhTls9MTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

Comment: have the same lens and the same problem. but as others have pointed out it only happens when the camera is worn, not when shooting.